# How to display the selected value in dropdown from datastore using java GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, drop-down-menu, selected, selectedvalue

Am using the below code in jsp to retrieve the selected value from datastore. but the last option> value is displaying by default. whats wrong in this syntax?

option> value="Monthly" selected="<%=order.getPeriod()%> =='Monthly'? true:false">Monthly

option> value="Quaterly" selected="<%=order.getPeriod()%> =='Quaterly'?true:false">Quaterly

Someone kindly help me to findout. thanks in advance.

Comment: i want output like, if the value in the cloumn is "monthly" means, the first value in the dropdown should be "monthly".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you close the jsp tag in the wrong place. It should be:

```
<option value="Monthly" <%=order.getPeriod().equals("Quaterly")? selected : "" %>>Quaterly</option>
```

Comment: Andrei Volgin, i changed it, but te same output is showing by default it displaying the last <option> value

Comment: i changed it. but it showing the same output. eventhough the .equals() returns correct value, it showing the last option value.                                                  <option value="Monthly" selected="false">Monthly</option>
<option value="Quaterly" selected="false">Quaterly</option>
<option value="Half_Yearly"selected="true">Half_Yearly</option>
<option value="Yearly" selected="false">Yearly</option>

Comment: It should be "selected", not "selected = true". I will update the response.

Comment: Andrei Volgin, got the correct output. thanks for the timely help. thanks a lot. the syntax is, <option value="Yearly" <%=order.getPeriod().equals("Yearly")? "selected" : "" %>>Yearly</option>

Comment: It is customary on StackOverflow to accept and upvote the correct answers to your questions. This will make people more willing to help you.

Answer (score 0):

got the output i needed, the correct syntax is,

< option value="Yearly" <%=order.getPeriod().equals("Yearly")? "selected" : "" %>>Yearly

just delete the space in-between angular bracket and option.